# Talking to Websphere XML access 'wps/config'

Tags: ibm, xml

I'm trying to talk to a remote XMLAccess tool part of WebSphere Portal on the internet at a url that looks like that http://site/wps/config Where can i get the IBM tool to do that (a link would be great)? or can i just do it by forging manually POST http requests?

Thanks for that.

Comment: Belongs on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are scripts called xmlaccess.sh and xmlaccess.bat that come with WebSphere Portal and are used for this purpose. They live under the PortalServer/bin directory in a typical Portal installation.

Comment: For further documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/admin/adxmltsk_cmdln_basic_syntax.dita